# How to prevent regular users to backup database, in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

How can I prevent/restrict regular users, that do have select rights granted on tables etc, to perform backup of Postgres database?

Is there a way to enable users to connect, select, update etc. tables in the database, but to disable them to backup database (e.g. via pgAdmin4)?

Comment: How, security wise, is `SELECT * FROM table` different than doing (some kind) of backups? If a user can do this SQL query, then he can back up the data...

Comment: `pg_dump` does nothing different. It simply runs `select * from ..` for every table.